# Can I use the logical OR operator with Strings in function arguments in JS? Function does not evaluate the second string (I think)

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, parameters, arguments

I check the backend through Vuex to conditionally render error messages. I have the following function:

```
const getByTitle = (memberTitle) => {
  return state.errors.find(e => e.meta.memberTitle === memberTitle)
       ?.content.error.title;   
}
```

Now, as an argument I would like to pass 2 strings, as there are 2 options in this component.

```
getNumber() {
  return this.getErrorByMemberId('B2Bvr' || 'Cvr' || undefined);
},
```

If the correct value in the backend is **Cvr**, then in this case I unfortunately don't get the error message (because it comes after **B2Bvr**). If I change the order of the arguments (see following snippet) abd put the correct value first (**Cvr**), then it works and correctly displays the error message.

```
getNumber() {
  return this.getErrorByMemberId('Cvr' || 'B2Bvr' || undefined);
},
```

Why does it stop in the first argument? And does not evaluate the second one? Which is the correct way to use Logical OR operators in parameters?

Answer (score 1):

It stops at the first argument because that's the first argument that is truthy, so the other arguments are ignored.  If you attempted to call the function with `undefined` first (falsy value), it would skip that one and send the second argument.

One way to accomplish your intended goal would be to send all possible arguments as an array of arguments and use [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) in your function:

```js
getNumber() {
  return this.getErrorByMemberId(['Cvr', 'B2Bvr', undefined]);
},
```

```js
const getByTitle = (memberTitleArray) => {
  return state.errors.find(e => memberTitleArray.includes(e.meta.memberTitle))
       ?.content.error.title;   
}
```

Comment: The second way sounds super good. It was actually the way that I approached it before you answered the question! 
Actually regarding your comment's first sentence, because I am really interested to find out what is going on. It did not stop because it was truthy. It was actually falsy and it never went to the second argument that was truthy.